# iOS Swift Playgrounds Views Are Not Centered

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift-playground

So the picture says it all. I basically have a title and set the width of the label to the entire view's width and I have the text alignment to be centered. However, it's apparent that it's off to the right a little bit. I think that the playground view is cutting off a part of the view. Can anyone please tell me how to center the UILabel properly please? Thanks!

[image: Playground View]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: view.frame.width, height: 60))
        title.textAlignment = .center
        title.text = "Hello World!"
        title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        title.textColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(title)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Can you add a UIView in the “center” and see where it shows up? This might help diagnose if it’s an issue with the whole view or just your label. Thanks

Comment: I have done so. The view is also a little to the right, exactly under the titleLabel. So it's a problem with the whole view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting view frames based on a view controller’s view’s frame in `viewDidLoad` will likely result in expected layout as auto layout has not completed its layout passes when `viewDidLoad` Is called. You should set your label’s frame from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` Instead. For example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.text = "Hello World!"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.textColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! It works like a charm. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Be sure to use titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, or this may not work.